# Create a new column in a data frame that is a sum, by category, or a different variable. (I used to do this in STATA with bysort egen total)

Tags: r

Pretty new to R. I need to create the new column to the data table SUM_COUNT_STATE which is the sum of the COUNT column by state. This can be done in STATA with bysort STATE: `egen SUM_COUNT_STATE = total(COUNT)` or in Excel with `sumif()`.

```
STATE   COUNT   SUM_COUNT_STATE
FL  70.88   210.42
RI  99.76   222.75
TX  34.55   160.89
CA  99.31   380.39
PA  80.12   175.22
PA  95.1    175.22
RI  13.72   222.75
FL  88.64   210.42
RI  79.31   222.75
CA  62.49   380.39
TX  26.89   160.89
FL  50.9    210.42
TX  4.33    160.89
TX  95.12   160.89
CA  82.8    380.39
CA  48.57   380.39
CA  87.22   380.39
RI  29.96   222.75
```

I tried:

```
DATAFRAME <- group_by(DATAFRAME, STATE)
DATAFRAME$SUM_COUNT_STATE <- sum(DATAFRAME$COUNT)
```

This just gives one sum for the whole column, not by state.

```
DATAFRAME <- data.frame(rowsum(DATAFRAME$COUNT,DATAFRAME$STATE))
```

This also gives one sum for the whole column, not by state.

```
SUM_COUNT_STATE <- rowsum(DATAFRAME$COUNT,DATAFRAME$STATE)
```

This appears to give the correct calculation, but leaves only one row for each STATE, but the output is a matrix whcih I can't seem to reattach to the original dataframe.

(In my actual data, I'm using ZIP_CODE not state) and the resulting matrix seems to use the ZIP_CODE as the _N, rather than as a named column)

Comment: `ave()` can do this: `DATAFRAME$SUM_COUNT_STATE <- ave(DATAFRAME$COUNT, DATAFRAME$STATE, FUN=sum)`

Answer (score 0):

```
tmp <- tapply(DATAFRAME$COUNT, DATAFRAME$STATE, sum) #Obtains sums by state
DATAFRAME$SUM_COUNT_STATE <- tmp[DATAFRAME$STATE] # adds a new column using DATAFRAME$STATE
#as index to subset the vector with the sums by the namees of its elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate it and create new DF1 by sub setting State with agg and lastly create a new column in DF by using DF1

```
agg <- aggregate(COUNT ~ STATE, DF, sum)
colnames(y)[2] <- c("Sum")
DF1 <- agg[DF$STATE,]
DF$Count_Sum <- DF1$Sum
```